# Extended windows

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, windowing

I have an always one application, listening to a Kafka stream, and processing events.  Events are part of a session.  And I need to do calculations based off of a sessions data.  I am running into a problem trying to correctly run my calculations due to the length of my sessions.  90% of my sessions are done after 5 minutes.  99% are done after 1 hour.  Sessions may last more than a day, due to this being a real-time system, there is no determined end.  Session are unique, and show never collide.

I am looking for a way where I can process a window multiple times, either with an initial wait period and processing any later events after that, or a pure process per event type structure.  I will need to keep all previous events around(ListState), as well as previously processed values(ValueState).

I previously thought `allowedLateness` would allow me to do this, but it seems the lateness is only considered for when the event should have been processed, it does not extend an actual window.  `GlobalWindows` may also work, but I am unsure if there is a way to process a window multiple times.  I believe I can used an `evictor` with `GlobalWindows` to purge the Windows after a period of inactivity(although admittedly, I did not research this yet, because I was unsure of how to trigger a `GlobalWindow` multiple times.

Any suggestions on how to achieve what I am looking to do would be greatly appreciated, I would also be happy to clarify any points needed.

Comment: How do you differentiate sessions? Have you looked into SessionWindows? https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#session-windows

Answer (score 0):

If [`SessionWindows`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#session-windows) won't do the job, then you can use `GlobalWindows` with a custom `Trigger` and `Evictor`. The Trigger interface has onElement and timer-based callbacks that can fire whenever and as often as you like. If you go down this route, then yes, you'll also need to implement an Evictor to dispose of elements when they are no longer needed.

The [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#triggers) and the [source code](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/release-1.4/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/triggers) are helpful when trying to understand how this all fits together.